# Access Terminal in IntelliJ Enterprise edition 2017

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm on a windows 10 64 bit box.  I need to open the terminal inside intellij 2017.1.  According to google the key command for this is alt-F12 but that combination of keystrokes does nothing apparent for me.

Is there an alternative way to open the console inside intellij that I might be overlooking?

Thanks!

Comment: Everything is documented at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html. Make sure Terminal plug-in is enabled.

Comment: Obviously I checked there first.  Alt-F12 is assigned to a different function so it appears there is a conflict.  How do I enable the terminal plug in?  I saw no specifics on that.

Comment: See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html and http://i.imgur.com/Ghp2sDH.png.

Answer (score 0):

It has clearly explained in the documentation provided by the JetBrains.

- To find the terminal related details please use the following link.

  [IntelliJ IDEA Terminal](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html)
- If you want to configure the key bindings please refer the following
  link.

  [IntelliJ IDEA Keyboard Shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

Answer (score 0):

That shortcut is correct, to run embedded local terminal press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>. But you should make sure that the `Terminal plugin` is enabled. The plugin is bundled with IntelliJ IDEA and is activated by default, if it is not the case, you can enable it, go to `Settings > Preferences > Plugins`

[image]